# How do I convert MSC number from HLR lookup to geolocation?

Tags: mobile, geolocation, gsm

If I have the number of a phone's MSC (Mobile Switching Center) that I get from its HLR Lookup, how can I identify the location from that number? Do the cellular companies publish the locations or is there a service that does this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the location of the MSC itself then there is nothing in the number that a will tell you the geographic location of the MSC (unless you have some operator lookup table which they would be very unlikely to provide).

Additionally, with the move towards IP core networks and distributed architectures for MSC's, what was once a 'MSC' may now be distributed across several locations.

This is because in the past a single entity called an MSC would both terminate the links from the radio access networks and contain all the 'brains' and signalling to decide how to route your call. With more modern architectures the 'brains' and the part that handles the actuating switching of the speech part of the call are generally on different nodes, and more often than not in different locations.

If you meant to determine the location of the phone itself from the MSC number then again that will depend on the network - modern distributed architectures mean the node indicated by the 'MSC' might handle calls from anywhere in a given region or even country. Even if it is an older network with 'monolithic' MSC's (rather than the newer distributed architecture ones), a single MSC will still likely serve too large region, relatively speaking, to be much use to you.